# How to hide `CalledProcessError` when using iPython's `%%bash`?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm preparing a notebook-based presentation.

This involve commands examples, including some with non-zero exit statuses.

Hence some results like this :

For a cell containing the following code :

```
%%bash
false
```

I get :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[79], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'false\n')

File ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2478, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2476 with self.builtin_trap:
   2477     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2478     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2480 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2481 # when using magics with decodator @output_can_be_silenced
   2482 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2483 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py:153, in ScriptMagics._make_script_magic.<locals>.named_script_magic(line, cell)
    151 else:
    152     line = script
--> 153 return self.shebang(line, cell)

File ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py:305, in ScriptMagics.shebang(self, line, cell)
    300 if args.raise_error and p.returncode != 0:
    301     # If we get here and p.returncode is still None, we must have
    302     # killed it but not yet seen its return code. We don't wait for it,
    303     # in case it's stuck in uninterruptible sleep. -9 = SIGKILL
    304     rc = p.returncode or -9
--> 305     raise CalledProcessError(rc, cell)

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'false\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

This kind of traceback is rather irrelevant to my presentation, and I'd like to hide it and I didn't find how so far.

According to the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-bash), `%%bash` is an alias for `%%script bash`:

So I tried in my IPython :

- `%%script --no-raise-error bash false`

This issued `/usr/bin/false: /usr/bin/false: cannot execute binary file`

- `%shebang --no-raise-error bash false` (Based on the usage presented in the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-script)).

But since it issued `UsageError: Line magic function 'shebang' not found.` I think it could be a typo in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually while writing this question, I found out that the non-zero exiting command shouldn't be a part of the script usage.

Here's the actual usage :

This issues the error :

```
%%script bash
echo "foo" && false
```

Output :

```
foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('script', 'bash', 'echo "foo" && false\n\n')

File ~/.virtualenvs/dojo-pytest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2478, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2476 with self.builtin_trap:
   2477     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2478     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2480 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2481 # when using magics with decodator @output_can_be_silenced
   2482 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2483 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~/.virtualenvs/dojo-pytest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py:305, in ScriptMagics.shebang(self, line, cell)
    300 if args.raise_error and p.returncode != 0:
    301     # If we get here and p.returncode is still None, we must have
    302     # killed it but not yet seen its return code. We don't wait for it,
    303     # in case it's stuck in uninterruptible sleep. -9 = SIGKILL
    304     rc = p.returncode or -9
--> 305     raise CalledProcessError(rc, cell)
```

This doesn't :

```
%%script bash --no-raise-error
echo "foo" && false
```

Output :

```
foo
```